# JQuery Cycle, stop at final slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I am using JQuery slide for showing some div's on my website.

Users have a previous and next button to navigate.

Lets say I have 4 slides on the slideshow.

By default, hitting previous when I'm at the first slide will take me to slide 4, and hitting next on slide 4 will take me to slide 1.

How can I stop this behaviour and put a stop point and each end of the slideshow?

Plugin documentation is [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html), sadly my skill at this point doesn't let me do much about it though.

Comment: Hide the next button on the fourth slide and hide the previous button on the first slide

Comment: It may have something to do about the div image width. Depends on how you organize your image frames.

Comment: @PitaJ This is what I ended up doing, but I'm certain there could be a cleaner way to do this